# Getting error whenever I try to get value of combobox

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to display the value of a combobox in a dynamic text output. It works on the first keyframe using myCombobox.value,  but moving to the next keyframe using gotoAndStop(2) and trying to do the same thing

```
myTextField.text = String(myOtherCombobox.value);
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

This happens on other keyframes too, and I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create your combo-box with actionscript, it doesn't exist on the other frames, so it's null. You'll have to either recreate it on the other frame or redesign that part of your program. Generally you should only use keyframes in the main timeline for separate states of the program. In other words: You usually don't need to have the same object exist in both frames.

EDIT: just read your question again, and the TextField object could also be null.

Comment: I made it using flash - one of the default components.
I made it on the second keyframe, and have the code that calls it on the second keyframe too.

Comment: oops type-o, sorry I meant that stuff made in the IDE on one frame doesn't get carried over to any other frames

Comment: Well I am not really carrying anything over. I built my app so it works in steps (it is a calculator). The user enters values on the first keyframe, I save them to global variables and move the user to the next keyframe and load the globals then do some math. 

The user has to enter more values on the second keyframe, so there I build a new user interface with new components that aren't carried over from any other frame. I am using the code locally to each frame too.

Comment: OK, then have you tried to debug it, and see which object is null?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are trying to get the value from the combobox before Flash has managed to register the component.

If possible try to split the action over 2 frames or use a timer to delay the reading of the value.